# KeyAvailable does not reset to false

Tags: c#

I have a bit of c# code that's supposed to check and print if you pressed a key or not in the console

```
while (true)
{
   if (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Press a key");
      Thread.Sleep(1000); //wait 1 second
   }
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine("You pressed a key. ");
      Thread.Sleep(1000); //wait 1 second
   }
}
```

Expected result

```
Press a key.
Press a key.
Press a key.
Press a key.
You pressed a key.
Press a key.
Press a key.
Press a key.
```

Actual result

```
Press a key.
Press a key.
Press a key.
Press a key.
You pressed a key.
You pressed a key.
You pressed a key.
You pressed a key.
You pressed a key.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Console.KeyAvailable` to reset you need to read the key with `Console.ReadKey();`

```
while (true)
{
    if (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press a key");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //wait 1 second
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed a key.");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //wait 1 second
    }
}
```